# Load javascript before onPageFinished

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to inject some javascript to a page. I can do that on the `onPageFinished` event, which works just fine. But the problem is there are several images on the page and it takes a while to load all these images and call the `onPageFinished`. The user may start interacting with the page before that call is made.

Is it possible to load the javascript just after the html but before any other resource is loaded? I tried `onPageStarted` but this is called before the html is loaded so my javascript doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API exposed to do the same but you can do that trying to figure out after how much % of page load you can inject you `JS`, that sounds weird but can help you.

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

                //change your progress bar
            }


        });
```